# Filter query based on paramater

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

Creating a workbook tile using KQL which utilises parameters - in this case VirtualMachines.

If I run the following with only 1 VM selected in the paramater, the results are displayed. If I select 2 or more VMs there is an error explaining the results could not be parsed, with the error output showing VM1, VM2.

Delimiter configured for the parameter is ,

How could I correct the following query to work with multiple VirtualMachine parameter selections?

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| extend vmName = tostring(toupper(Computer))
| extend VM_Name = tostring(split(vmName,'.')[0]) 
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(Val) by VM_Name, Disk, _ResourceId
| where VM_Name in '{VirtualMachines:label}'
| top 30 by AggregatedValue asc
```

Thanks

Comment: Not that I'm all that up on kql, but taking a quick look at the docs relating to the "in" operator, I'm guessing that - much like other SQL syntaxes - the "in" comparative expression should be something like IN ('A', 'B', 'C').  I suspect that with the way you are passing your parameter, you're ending up with WHERE VM_Name IN ('VM1,VM2') - that is, your comma-separated string is just being passed as a single string.  You may need to use the split() function to transform the comma-separated string into an array that "IN" recognises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: For single value parameters in workbooks, the value of a parameter is just text, so you need to wrap it in quotes *inside* the query text

so if `VirtualMachines` is a single value param, you'd use it like this in a query:

```
...
| where machine == "{VirtualMachines}"
```

which then turns into

```
...
| where machine == "the value of the parameter"
```

at query time.

HOWEVER, when using *multi value dropdown params*, the parameter settings has options for what to use to for quote (`'` by default) and delimiter (`,`) by default, so you have to use it like this:

```
...
| where machine in ({VirtualMachines}) // note NO QUOTES HERE
```

which at query time gets resolved into

```
...
| where machine in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') // note NO QUOTES HERE
```

for multi value params, especially if optional, the best way to do this is with a let:

```
let machines = dynamic([{VirtualMachines}]); // turns into a KQL array,even if param is empty
```

because then you can use it like

```
let machines = dynamic([{VirtualMachines}]); // turns into a KQL array,even if param is empty
...
| where machine in (machines) // note NO QUOTES HERE
```

which will be syntactically valid even if there's no machines selected
(so you could do like `|where array_length(machines)==0 or machine in (machines)` to allow ALL machines if nothing is selected

Comment: Thanks John, this looks promising however when removing the ' from around the parameter only the server name of the first server is returned, everything after a hyphen is omitted. So for example 



let machines = dynamic([{VirtualMachines:label}])
print machines


will output


VM


while 


let vms_ = dynamic('{VirtualMachines:label}');
print vms


will output


VM-1, VM2


Inconsistent server naming standards unfortunately...

Appreciate your help.

Comment: basically: you need quotes in the query text if the parameter is a single value param in workbooks, you don't need quotes if it is a multivalue param, because the param formats itself as multi values.  note that i never said to use the `:label` specifier: that specifically formats multivales params as the label you would see in the dropdown, NOT the labels of the individual values

Answer (score 0):

> If I run the following with only 1 VM selected in the paramater, the results are displayed. If I select 2 or more VMs there is an error explaining the results could not be parsed, with the error output showing VM1, VM2.

Thanks to `Craig` for suggesting the same.

You should replace `["VM1", "VM2"]` with the actual parameter name that contains the selected `VMs`.

**Method : 1**

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| extend vmName = tostring(toupper(Computer))
| extend VM_Name = tostring(split(vmName,'.')[0]) 
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(Val) by VM_Name, Disk, _ResourceId
| where VM_Name in ("CH1-DMAVM","SQL01","AppBE00","DC01")
| top 30 by AggregatedValue asc
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Method 2:**

To make the query work with multiple `VirtualMachine` parameter selections, Instead of using the `in` operator, you should use the `in` operator along with the `dynamic` function to construct the appropriate **dynamic expression**.

```
let selectedVMs = dynamic(["SQL01", "SQL10", "DC01","AppBE00"]);
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| extend Disk = tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| extend vmName = tostring(toupper(Computer))
| extend VM_Name = tostring(split(vmName, '.')[0])
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(Val) by VM_Name, Disk, _ResourceId
| where VM_Name in (selectedVMs)
| top 30 by AggregatedValue asc
```

By using the `in (selectedVMs)` expression, the query will filter the results based on the `VM names` present in the `selectedVMs` array.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: and in this case, probably more specifically `let selectedVMs = dynamic([{VirtualMachines}]);` to account for the parameter, which was the original request

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I achieved this by using the following:

```
let machines = dynamic('{VirtualMachines:label}');
let vms = split(machines, ', ');
InsightsMetrics
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms"
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" and Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| extend vmName = tostring(toupper(Computer))
| extend VM_Name = tostring(split(vmName,'.')[0]) 
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(Val) by VM_Name, Disk, _ResourceId
| where VM_Name in~ (vms)
| top 30 by AggregatedValue asc
```

Comment: fyi: `{virtualmachines:label}` will ONLY format PART of the labels with multivalue parameters.  after a number of them, you might get "+20 more" as part of the text.  you also need to be very careful with using JUST resource names.  Virtual machines *might* have a rule that they are uniquely named across subscriptions/resourcegroups, etc but that is NOT true for all kinds of resources

Comment: in fact, if you KNOW that the machines are azure VM's, might better off using the ids directly and comparing the selected VM resource ids directly to the `_ResourceId` field instead of the split/parsing of vm names

Comment: Thanks @JohnGardner you are right, and when the parameter= 'all' then 0 results are returned (because virtualmachines:label = all( as well so will use your suggestion of comparing against the resource ID